# How to enable `flymake-display-err-menu-for-current-line` in terminal for emacs?

Tags: python, user-interface, emacs, terminal, flymake

I'm using `flymake-python`. When I execute `flymake-display-err-menu-for-current-line`, emacs always complains that `Can not put GUI menu on this terminal`.

Does anyone have ideas about how to show flymake's message in a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the following in your emacs configuration:

```
(setq flymake-gui-warnings-enabled nil)
```

You might consider using [flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck) instead of flymake. It's under active development and should work fine for python without any additional configuration.